# how to get the "Object HTML" instead of the "Object Object" in Vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm counting the number of characters on two textareas with a method called charactersLeft() that receives this.$refs.eventName or this.$refs.eventDescription

How can I get the HTML Element for the second textarea (this.$refs.eventDescription) instead of the component object?

[image]

```
<template>
...
TEXT AREA 1:::::::::::::::
<div class="w-full md:w-full px-3 mb-6">
  <label >Event Name</label >
  <span class="text-red-600">*</span>
  <div class="relative">
    <textarea
        v-bind:class="{ 'border-gray-500': !$v.event.name.$error, 'border-bc-red-error border': $v.event.name.$error }"
        v-model="event.name"
        name="name"
        maxlength = "80"
        ref="eventName"
    ></textarea>
    <div v-if="$v.event.name.$dirty"
         class="pointer-events-none absolute top-0 mt-4 right-0 flex items-center pr-4">
      <i v-if="!$v.event.name.required"
         class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle text-bc-red-error"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex justify-between relative">
    <span class="absolute block text-sm right-0">{{charactersLeft(this.$refs.eventName)}}</span>
  </div>
</div>

TEXT AREA 2:::::::::::::::
<div class="w-full md:w-full px-3 mb-6">
  <label>Event Description</label>
  <span class="text-red-600">*</span>
  <div class="relative">
    <textEditor ref="eventDescription" v-bind:value="event.description" v-on:input="event.description = $event"></textEditor>
  </div>

  <div class="flex justify-between relative">
    <span class="absolute block text-sm right-0">{{charactersLeft(this.$refs.eventDescription)}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
...
</template>

methods: {
charactersLeft(e) {
      console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+e)
      console.dir(e)
      if (e != null && typeof this.event[e.name] !== 'undefined') {
        //console.log(this.event[e.name])
        let char = this.event[e.name] !== 'undefined' ? this.event[e.name].length : 0;
        let limit = e.maxLength;
        return (limit - char) + ' / ' + limit;
      }
      return '0/0';
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution, I created a conditional

```js
charactersLeft(e) {
      let output = "0/0";
      if (e != null) {
        //check for Editor Component Events
        if (e._isVue) {
          //output from Editor Component
          output = `${e.maxlength - e.tagLength} / ${e.maxlength}`;
        } else {
          //output from TextArea
          let char = this.event[e.name].length;
          let limit = e.maxLength;
          output = limit - char + " / " + limit;
        }
      }

      return output;
    },
```

Codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue2editor-wrapped-example-forked-n7o2q

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <p>1. Count the amount of remaining characters for Editor Component</p>
      <p>
        2. Editor Component must limit the amount of characters given by
        "maxlength" attribute
      </p>
      <p>3. Reuse charactersLeft() method for both textAreas</p>
    </div>
    <p>----------------- INIT WORKING FINE ------------------</p>
    <span
      ><h2>
        WORKING FINE:
        {{ charactersLeft($refs.eventDescription) }}
      </h2></span
    >
    <textarea
      v-model="event.description"
      name="description"
      :maxlength="30"
      ref="eventDescription"
    ></textarea>
    <p>------------------- END WORKING FINE ----------------</p>

    <p>----------------- INIT NOT WORKING ------------------</p>
    <span
      ><h2>NOT WORKING: {{ charactersLeft($refs.eventTag) }}</h2></span
    >
    <editor :tag.sync="event.tag" :maxlength="50" ref="eventTag"></editor>
    <div v-html="event.tag"></div>
    <p>------------------- END NOT WORKING ----------------</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Editor from "./components/Editor.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Editor,
  },
  data: () => ({
    event: {
      description: "this is the description",
      tag: "",
    },
  }),

  methods: {
    charactersLeft(e) {
      let output = "0/0";
      if (e != null) {
        //check for Editor Component Events
        if (e._isVue) {
          //output from Editor Component
          output = `${e.maxlength - e.tagLength} / ${e.maxlength}`;
        } else {
          //output from TextArea
          let char = this.event[e.name].length;
          let limit = e.maxLength;
          output = limit - char + " / " + limit;
        }
      }

      return output;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: left;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Editor.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="editor-wrapper">
    <vue-editor
      @text-change="onTextChange"
      v-model="editorContent"
      ref="editor"
    ></vue-editor>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { VueEditor } from "vue2-editor";

export default {
  name: "Editor",
  props: {
    tag: String,
    maxlength: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      tagLength: 0,
    };
  },

  computed: {
    editorContent: {
      get() {
        return this.tag;
      },
      set(updatedContent) {
        this.$emit("update:tag", updatedContent);
      },
    },
  },

  methods: {
    onTextChange: function (newContents, oldContents) {
      const { quill } = this.$refs.editor;
      const contentLength = quill.getLength() - 1;

      if (contentLength <= this.maxlength) {
        this.tagLength = contentLength;
      } else {
        quill.setContents(oldContents);
      }
    },
  },

  components: {
    VueEditor,
  },
};
</script>
```